# How can I change location settings in Android without going to Settings manually?

Tags: android, google-maps, settings

I would like to use Google Maps feature to ask user whether s/he wants to turn on wifi, location (or change mode) without going to *Settings* where user have to change it manually.

Here are some examples of what I would like to do *programmatically*:

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

It should be possible if Google Maps has it.

Comment: "It should be possible if Google Maps has it" -- that is not strictly true, as Google Maps is a system app and therefore can do things that ordinary SDK apps cannot. In this case, while Maps has been able to do that for a while, this will only become available to us when the new Play Services 7.0 SDK becomes available: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/03/google-play-services-70-places-everyone.html

Comment: I've added your screenshot to the question itself, and I've removed the noise words ("thanks").

Answer (score 0):

You can write code to display an alert dialog on the top of your map activity. Here is an example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm...");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to go to wifi settings?");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    // alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    // Activity transfer to wifi settings
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
                }
            });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("no",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to invoke NO event

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
```

Code is self explanatory.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: this is exactly my current solution  :)

Comment: You can accept the solution so that others can refer to this too!! Thanks!!